# MVC Html Helper Rendering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I was wondering if it's possible to render an Html Helper in a View inside a codeblock. So instead of:

```
<% = Html.TextBox("sometextbox", "somethingelse") %>
```

I want to do:

```
<% 
switch(SomeParameter) 
{
   case "blah":
       Html.TextBox("sometextbox", "somethingelse")
   break;
}
%>
```

And have this render. Of course as it is, it wont render, so is there a way to programically decide if a textbox can be added without having to have a million delimiters in the page to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should you be putting logic like that in your view?

Comment: I'm still toying with the design. At some point it has to end up int he view, the Html Elements int his case are driven from a database table, so I'm not really sure where it could go and still end up int he view. I may have 1 to 10 parameters programically added depending on what's in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% 
    switch(SomeParameter) 
    { 
        case "blah": 
            %><%=Html.TextBox("sometextbox", "somethingelse")%><%
            break; 
    } 
%>
```

`<%= %>` is just a shorthand notation for `Response.Write()` though so the following should work too.

```
<% 
    switch(SomeParameter) 
    { 
        case "blah": 
            Response.Write(Html.TextBox("sometextbox", "somethingelse"));
            break; 
    } 
%>
```

All the HtmlHelpers return a string and don't output to the response stream directly by design.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed, I don't know why I didn't think of that since that's part of the classic model.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

```
  <% switch (SomeParameter)
       {
           case "blah": %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("sometextbox", "somethingelse") %>
    <% break;
       } %>
```

Comment: Close, I was trying to avoid having to separate my delimiters for each break.  Thank you for your response!

Comment: Sorry me being simple don't know why I didn't give the solution above :D

Comment: Probably for the same reason I didn't think of it, sometimes we don't process what we know hehe :) Thanks for your time.